# Will a Siamese fighting fish fit in my aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, betta

I have a 50 gallon tank in which I have four Mollies, one Angelfish and one Blue Dwarf Gourami. I want to add one male Siamese Fighting Fish (a.k.a Betta) and my tank for me is then complete. Question is; will this be ok, as the other fish are happy, and all friends, and yes they are all young. Will a fighter fish be a hassle?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! This question has already been answered - although not with your specific fish. I suspect, however, that the answers there will help you. :)

Comment: I wouldn't with an angelfish in there. Maybe if you got a female betta it could work.